# Audio Video mixing out of sync with ffmpeg

Tags: video, audio, ffmpeg

I am trying to mix a `wav` file and video file using `ffmpeg` to get a `mpg` file.
The files are getting mixed but the issue is that the audio runs ahead of video.

Please suggest a way to get them in sync.

Comment: Which command do you use? What are the files exactly?